# How to make the vs code icons extension reflect the actual file type?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I installed this extension for vs code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons&ssr=false#review-details

I am seeing the words "js" appear for react files, vs icons should be able to distinguish react from from regular javascript, and mark react files with the react icon, how do I adjust the settings so that react files have the blue icon?

current settings

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "terminal.foreground" : "#6EFF3E",
    "terminal.background" : "#383737",
},
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Tomorrow Night Blue",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"vsicons.associations.fileDefault.file": null,

}
```

Comment: A React file is a JavaScript file. If VS Code is configured to treat JS files as `javascriptreact` you'll get the atom-ish symbol, IIRC. AFAIK the file contents are not introspected to guess what you mean by `.js`.

Comment: I figured it out, all I had to do was go to "change language mode" from the command palette and choose "auto detect", now vs code is showing the react icon for react files